# Troubleshooting DC to DC converter IC XL7005A

Tags: dc-dc-converter, schematics

I have a display control unit of a chinese branded e-bike which is not working properly (model number Ak47...seriously).
I checked the voltages on the board and stumbled upon that DC to DC converter XL7005A. On pin SW I can measure 0.9V. I have tried to figure out what the output voltage should be giving the voltage divider on the feedback pin FB, but no luck. Too less experience :(
I have noticed that the Shottky diode is getting warm, so I thought maybe it is dead. After removing the diode the converter got immediately hot. Is this normal? I don't get how the diode is preventing the IC to be short circuit.
The display unit should run on 48V, but I am running it with 31V from a bench power supply. So pin Vin is ~30V and enable Pin En is set low.

I have studied computer science, so I know basic electronics but as you can tell, that's not enough for this type of problems :D

Thank you in advance :)

[image: reference schematics for the IC]

Original board pictures:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUCKL.jpg

UPDATE:

I have measured the output voltage accross COUT (output capacitor) and got 0.6V. That seems too low. To my undterstanding, th converter is powering a Nuvoton Microcontroller (N76E003) that needs 2.5V - 5.5V to operate. Pin 9 of this µC is VDD and there I measure 0.6V.
How can I tell which voltage the IC is suppose to create?
On the feedback Pin of the Converter I can measure 2.47kOhm. According to the shown schematics R1 is 3300Ohm (reading 3301) and R2 is 10000Ohm (reading 1002).

I also looked at SW and the output voltage with my oscilloscope with a 1:10th probe.
On SW I can see a 30V square wave with 24kHz. Output is oscilating between 0.4V and 0.8V. Feedback voltage is 0.17V.

2nd UPDATE:

I have cut the trace that is going to pin VDD of the Nuvoton µC and now the converter is creating 4.98V. Feeding 4V directly to the µC is heating it up. It Seems that the µC is dead.

Output:
[image: Output capacitor voltage]
Pin SW:
[image: Pin SW voltage]

Comment: The Schottky diode is an essential component in a buck converter and its normal for it to get warm. I don't understand why you would remove it. Removing it would prevent the inductor from discharging into the output capacitor and load and would result in a huge voltage spike at the switch emitter. Also, you need to measure the output voltage across the output capacitor and not the switch emitter.

Comment: ah yes, you are right. The capacitor in the diagram at the output should be the tree parallel caps near the inductor, am I right?

Comment: When testing the converter did you disconnect the load?

Comment: _”so I thought maybe it is dead. After removing the diode”_ Please stop believing components are broken and unsoldering them at random.

Comment: If the problem was that something downstream from the regulator had a short circuit and the regulator was working, after removing the diode and powering it may now have damaged the regulator. If the voltage it did output to the rest of the board was fine, it can be just that your measuring device like a generic multimeter is not suitable for measuring the switch node as it may switch at too high frequency for your multimeter. Components have a purpose and removing components may allow other components to get damaged.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. 
I don't know how to remove the load. At least one of the load is a µC that needs min 2.5V to operate, but it just gets 0.6V from the converter.
I have replaced the diode and the values are still the same, so no damage to the IC.
Output of the Converter is 0.6V

Comment: The part regulates to 1.25V on the feedback pin. So for R1 = 10k and R2 = 3k3 that makes 1.66V, which seems like a uncommon voltage. If the resistor values are reversed the output should be 5V, which would make more sense.

Comment: My bad, I mistyped. 10k is parallel to the cap. So you are correct. 5V makes more sense :D

Comment: So, do you have 1.25 V on the feedback pin?

Comment: No, I have 0.17V on feedback pin and 0.6V on output

Comment: I see 3V squarewave on SW and 40-60mV on output not 30V and 0.6V. Why do you think it's 10x larger? 1:10th probe?

Comment: Yes I have used a 1:10th probe

Comment: Something is probably shorted downstream. My go-to methods include thermal camera and check for hotspots and if nothing shows up, apply current limited 3.3/5/whatever output voltage the converter is supposed to give and check for what’s heating up.

Comment: I have cut the trace that is going to pin VDD of the Nuvoton µC and now te converter is creating 4.98V. It seems that the µC is shorted..
Thank you all for your help.